# How can I display a DuckDuckGo search box with an image to its right on the same line as text to its left?

Tags: html, css

I would like to display a DuckDuckGo search box with text to its left and a magnifying glass image to its right, all on the same line. At the moment I am getting the text on one line and then the search box and image on the next, even though I have wrapped them all in `display: inline`. How can I get them on the same line? My code is as follows:

```css
form input[type="text"] {
  height: 16px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-left: 24px;
  font-size: 13px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  vertical-align: top;
  maxlength="255";
}

.display-inline {display:inline;  }
```

```html
<div class="display-inline">text
<form method="get" id="search" action="http://duckduckgo.com/">
<input type="hidden" name="sites" value="foobar.com"/>
<input type="hidden" name="k8" value="#000000"/>
<input type="hidden" name="k9" value="#0000ff"/>
<input type="hidden" name="kaa" value="#880088"/>
<input type="hidden" name="kt" value="a"/>
<input type="text" name="q" maxlength="255" placeholder="&nbsp;..."/>
&nbsp;<img src="images/image.gif" height="20" width="20">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form is block-level by default.

```css
form {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
form > input[type="text"] {
  height: 16px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-left: 24px;
  font-size: 13px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div>text
  <form method="get" id="search" action="http://duckduckgo.com/">
    <input type="hidden" name="sites" value="foobar.com" />
    <input type="hidden" name="k8" value="#000000" />
    <input type="hidden" name="k9" value="#0000ff" />
    <input type="hidden" name="kaa" value="#880088" />
    <input type="hidden" name="kt" value="a" />
    <input type="text" name="q" maxlength="255" placeholder=" ..." />
    <input type="image" src="/favicon.ico" height="20" width="20" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Many thanks. The snippet works fine, but for some reason it's not working in my code. I must have something there that's interfering with it.

Comment: Fixed now :) I took `form` out of my reset.